# changing return type from void to int in user def strcpy function

Tags: int, void

I have made string copy user defined function with void return type. How can i change my function if i want int return type?

My code for string copy function with void return type.

```
void strcpy(char arr1[], char arr[]) {

    for(int i=0;arr[i]<='\0';i++)
    {

      arr1[i]=arr[i];
    }
```

Comment: You need to specify what you want the return value to mean, not just what type (int) you want it to be. Also, what language is this? It looks like C, but could be something else because many languages use similar syntax. If it is C, be careful about buffer overflows in case the destination char array is smaller than the source!

Comment: its c++. i have some basic idea of this.to copy string with return type int , the function will execute in a loop and copy the addresses of the string and then it will store that in other string. i just don't know how to shape it up.